# Setting up a container from a users github source

Tags: docker, go, dns, debian, docker-compose

**Can be closed, not sure how to do it.**

I am to be quite frank lost right now, the user whom published his source on github somehow failed to update the installation instructions when he released a new branch. Now, I am not dense, just uneducated when it comes to docker. I would really appreciate a push in the right direction. If I am missing any information from this post, please allow me to provide it in the comments.

**Current Setup**

- **O/S** - Debian 8 Minimal (Latest kernel)
- **Hardware** - 1GB VPS (KVM)
- **Docker** - Installed with Compose ([# docker info](https://i.gyazo.com/60ea982c10d61bf3b0e659facdb052db.png))

I am attempting to setup this (https://github.com/pboehm/ddns/tree/docker_and_rework), first I should clone this git to my working directory? Lets say /home for example. I will run the following command;

```
git clone -b docker_and_rework https://github.com/pboehm/ddns.git
```

Which has successfully cloned the source files into /home/ddns/... ([working dir](https://i.gyazo.com/6985c70c5ac9df46e3dd95ac82c290d2.png))

Now I believe I am supposed to go ahead and build something*, so I go into the following directory;

```
/home/ddns/docker
```

Inside contains a docker-compose.yml file, I am not sure what this does but by looking at it, it appears to be sending a bunch of instructions which I can only presume is to do with actually deploying or building the whole container/image or magical thing right? From here I go ahead and do the following;

```
docker-compose build
```

As we can see, I believe its building the container or image or whatever its called, you get my point ([here](https://i.gyazo.com/4a08555af74664d8df0f083c2133c268.png)). After a short while, that completes and we can see the following ([docker images running](https://i.gyazo.com/17fa869bf79924d66bf6c9583fc42fc7.png)). Which is correct, I see all of the dependencies in there, but things like;

```
go version
```

It does not show as a command, so I presume I need to run it inside the container maybe? If so I dont have a clue how, I need to run 'ddns.go' which is inside /home/ddns, the execution command is;

```
ddns --soa_fqdn=dns.stealthy.pro --domain=d.stealthy.pro backend
```

I am also curious why the front end web page is not showing? There should be a page like this;

http://ddns.pboehm.org/

But again, I believe there is some more to do I just do not know what??

Answer (score 0):

The instructions it runs that you probably care about are in the Dockerfile, which for that repo is in the docker/ddns/ directory. What you're missing is that Dockerfile creates an image, which is a template to create an instance. Every time you docker run you'll create a new instance from the image. `docker run docker_ddns go version` will create a new instance of the image, run go version and output it, then die. Running long running processes like the `docker_ddns-web` image probably does will run the process until something kills that process. The reason you can't see the web page is probably because you haven't run `docker-compose up` yet, which will create linked instances of all of the docker images specified in the docker-compose.yml file. Hope this helps

Comment: I am still a little lost, if I am wrong let me know. So far I have 'installed' **it** but I have not ran **it**, sort of like.. I have downloaded CC cleaner, installed it but not clicked the icon to run the program. To do that I would need to do things like "docker run docker_ddns-web" which would launch said action. I have attempted it and I noticed this (https://i.gyazo.com/de83745f463ecbd00c4466aede08c685.png), have I installed this into the wrong directories?

Comment: So I didn't actually look at the docker-compose.yml file that closely when I posted, but if you look at the yaml for the `ddns-web` it says that it mounts a volume and depends on a redis container already existing. You probably want to run `docker-compose up` like @Leon said to interact with the web container, and exec inside to run any one-off commands. Or mount the volume manually using the -v option to docker run. You might also want to start by understanding docker first, then move on to docker-compose. Docker-compose is for setting up a more complex environment of docker images

Comment: Thanks for the message paulski, I believe the actual docker build I provided above is not currently working, the master build is also not working/outdated and the original creator is not wanting to provide any further information as to versions he used, he has simply stated 'if you do not have the knowledge to set this up, you should not be hosting it and you can use my hosted version' which leads me to believe he is using github to advertise his own DDNS provider which will likely turn pay to use once enough people use it, thanks for your help anyway mate.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose build` will only build the images.

You need to run this. It will build and run them.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The `-d` option runs containers in the background

To check if it's running after `docker-compose up`

```
docker-compose ps
```

It will show what is running and what ports are exposed from the container.
Usually you can access services from your `localhost`

If you want to have a look inside the container

```
docker-compose exec SERVICE /bin/bash
```

Where SERVICE is the name of the service in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: You're talking to me like I understand what docker is, I have literally never used it before since 2 hours ago? Literally none of what you said I can relate to in my case, at all.

Comment: Actually, Leon is correct. You built the images. You didn't state that you did anything like `docker-compose up` which would start the containers. The command `docker images` just shows what images are available on the machine.